# How to add color to the lines when using arrowkeys?

Tags: java, javafx

The program will create lines according to which arrow key the user is pressing. I want to change the color from (default) black to red when the user presses the up key. What is wrong with this format?

```
 private void moveUp() {
    pane.getChildren().add(new Line(cX, cY, cX, cY - 10));
    cY -= 10;

    Line sLine = new Line(cX, cY, cX, cY - 10);
    sLine.setStroke(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Are you doing anything with `sLine`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic isn't that the variable that determines which line/direction of lines are going to be colored Red?

Comment: It's a variable you have declared, and assigned an object to. But in the snippet of code you have given, you have not done anything with that variable. So you have a line object but it's not included in any part of the GUI. Is it being used anywhere in the code that follows?

Comment: @RealSkeptic please look at my whole markup on the answers. From my understanding, that variable and the color that is assigned to it will show if the arrow pressed fits the coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but one would assume from the code snippet provided that you'd want sLine to be added to the pane.getChildren(), not the new Line.

So something like this:

```
 private void moveUp() {
    Line sLine = new Line(cX, cY, cX, cY - 10);
    sLine.setStroke(Color.RED);
    pane.getChildren().add(sLine);
    cY -= 10;
```

If this didn'nt answer your question, you might consider clarifying it a bit with more details.